# How to execute a method of the control when a binding property is changed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, scroll

I have a datagrid, and I am binding the selectedItem property. I know also that the DataGrid control, has a method ScrollIntoView that scroll the dataGrid to the selected item.

So I would like to know that if exists a way to execute the method ScrollIntoView of the dataGrid when I change the selectedItem in my viewModel.

My Datagrid is setted as multi item selection, if this is important thing, and I would like to use the MVVM pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) in your code behind and bind the selection in the grid to it. Then you can add a callback for when the value changes. You probably want something like this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItems",
            typeof(object[]),
            typeof(Control),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));
```

Define the callback function and add any appropriate logic.

Comment: I forgot to say that I would like to use the MVVM pattern.   Thanks.

Comment: You still can. I consider dependency properties an important part of the MVVM pattern. Could you please elaborate?